# Type-Parameterized Tests for namespace conflict

Tags: c++, googletest, type-parameter

My code is structured like below:

```
namespace A{
class baseClass{
 template<typename t> static ::boost::shared_ptr<t> create_obj();
};
}

namespace A{
 namespace B{
   class DerivedClass1 : public baseClass {
     void create_obj(){...};
   }
 }
}

namespace A{
 namespace C{
   class DerivedClass2 : public baseClass {
     void create_obj(){...};
   }
 }
}
```

There is a base class and around 5-6 derived classes which are all in different namespaces. I am trying to write a test for create_obj() using the google testing framework, using the type-parameterized test as the method needs to be tested for all derived classes. My test code is:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "baseClass.h"
#include "DerivedClass1.h"
#include "DerivedClass2.h"

using namespace A;
using namespace B;
using namespace C;

template<typename T> class sample_test : public ::testing::Test 
{
protected:
  boost::shared_ptr<TypeParam> = create_obj();
};

TYPED_TEST_CASE_P(sample_test);

TYPED_TEST_P(sample_test, firstTest)
{
  //do some testing
}

REGISTER_TYPED_TEST_CASE_P(sample_test, firstTest);
typedef ::testing::Types<DerivedClass1, DerivedClass2> tTypes;
INSTANTIATE_TYPED_TEST_CASE_P(mytest, sample_test, tTypes);
```

This code gives some template error as it doesn't know which create_obj() to call.

So I am trying to write a switch case or if-else scenario in my test which will call method from correct namespace. Something like

```
  template<typename T> class sample_test : public ::testing::Test 
    {
    protected:
      switch(T)
      {
        case DerivedClass1:
          //Call method like  A::B::create_obj()
        case DerivedClass2:
          //Call method like  A::C::create_obj()
     }
    };
```

But I obviously cannot give T as a parameter in switch case or even in if-else schenario. Is there any way to be able to achieve this?

P.S: Extremely sorry but I cannot post the code online. I hope this would suffice.

Comment: You don't have to post the whole code online (and shouldn't, in general) but you should still extract an MCVE. BTW: Consider `T::create_object()`.

Comment: Please provide some feedback. Was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the code you've posted, you can fix your test code by specifying the namespaces directly when you register your types, like this:

```
typedef ::testing::Types<A::B::DerivedClass1, A::C::DerivedClass2> tTypes;
```

However, since you did not post MCVE, I cannot be 100% sure it will work. In case it does not, you could use type traits to differentiate between different types during compile time:

```
if (std::is_same<T, A::B::DerivedClass1>::value)
    //Call method like  A::B::create_obj()
else if (std::is_same<T, A::C::DerivedClass2>::value)
    //Call method like  A::C::create_obj()
...
```

For more info, see the documentation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same

Comment: I don't have c++11 so "std::is_same" didn't work. Is there anything similar to it which I can use?

Comment: @Preeti Well `is_same` is actually in boost as well so you are good: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_same.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but neither std::is_same not boost::is_same worked. Both gave compilation error "Syntax error: if statement". But what finally worked was the below code which was suggested by @Ulrich Eckhardt

```
template<typename T> class sample_test : public ::testing::Test 
{
protected:
  boost::shared_ptr<T> testObj;
  testObject = T::create_obj();
};
```